# When I set button title, there is fade-off and fade-out effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

When I use `setTitle: forState:` method to set my button's title, there have the fade-out and fade-in effect.

```
- (void)respondsToTextField:(UITextField *)sender {

    if ([sender.text isEqualToString:@""]) {


        [_cancleOrConfirmButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else {

        [_cancleOrConfirmButton setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with it.

```
- (void)respondsToTextField:(UITextField *)sender {

    if ([sender.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

       [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
           [_cancleOrConfirmButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [_cancleOrConfirmButton layoutIfNeeded];
    }]; 

    }else {

    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
       [_cancleOrConfirmButton setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [_cancleOrConfirmButton layoutIfNeeded];
    }]; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When You set the button title, if do not want the effect, you can set the `titleLable.text` first.

Try this:

```
- (void)respondsToTextField:(UITextField *)sender {

    if ([sender.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

        _cancleOrConfirmButton.titleLabel.text = @"Cancel";
        [_cancleOrConfirmButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else {

        _cancleOrConfirmButton.titleLabel.text = @"Search";
        [_cancleOrConfirmButton setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working in my code:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[_cancleOrConfirmButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```